# Unable to trigger a mouse event on some of the widgets

Tags: c++, qt, mouseevent

I'm trying to trigger fake click events on QPushButtons.

```
ButtonsMap::ButtonsMap()
{

    m_b1 = new QPushButton("push me 1", this);
    m_b2 = new QPushButton("push me 2", this);
    m_b3 = new QPushButton("push me 3", this);
    m_b1->move(0,0);
    m_b2->move(0,40);
    m_b3->move(0,80);
    connect(m_b1, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(setclicked1()));
    connect(m_b2, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(setclicked2()));
    connect(m_b3, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(setclicked3()));
}
```

And then I use this slot to triggers them using a custum TouchEvent class (not QTouchEvent, something from scratch)

```
void TouchToMouse::NewTouchEvent(const TouchEvent& e ) {
...

    QWidget *target = clickTarget(m_mw, pos);
    switch (e.m_type) {
        case APPEAR:
            event = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, pos, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
            break;
        case MOVE:
            event = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseMove, pos, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
            break;
        case DISAPPEAR:
            event = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonRelease, pos, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
            break;
    }

    QApplication::postEvent(target, event);*

}
```

My problem is: it works, but only for the first button `m_b1`, even though `QWidget *target` points to the right widget (I checked the adresses). It seems like `m_b2` and `m_b3` never do receive those events. Any idea on what might be going wrong?

Comment: How are the coordinates stored in `pos`? Have you tried to map them to the target widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events sent using *postEvent()* are sent to the event queue and dispatched the next time the event loops runs. Is it possible that somehow after the first event your event loop stops? Try calling *QApplication::processEvents()* to make sure all events currently in the queue are processed.